# How do I perform an automatic calculation on a column in a table using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to create a table in SQL Server :

[image]

I needed to create a column that is the final payment column that automatically generates its values by getting the difference between two other tables what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15).  eg

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products
(
     ProductID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
   , QtyAvailable smallint
   , UnitPrice money
   , InventoryValue AS QtyAvailable * UnitPrice
);
```